# Same binary but different assembly instructions at runtime - Windows 7

Tags: windows, assembly, binary

For a bit of background, I was playing around with anti-debug techniques. To prevent software breakpoints, one can search at runtime for 0xCC inside a memory segment. Code example here -> https://github.com/LordNoteworthy/al-khaser/blob/master/al-khaser/AntiDebug/SoftwareBreakpoints.cpp

Instead of checking for only one function, I wanted to test the whole `.text` section at runtime and compute the hash of the section. After some research I ended up with something like that.

```cpp
int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HMODULE imageBase = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER imageDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)imageBase;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS imageHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((SIZE_T)imageBase + imageDosHeader->e_lfanew);

    SIZE_T base = (SIZE_T)imageBase + (SIZE_T)imageHeader->OptionalHeader.BaseOfCode;
    SIZE_T end = (SIZE_T)base (SIZE_T)imageHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfCode;

    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while (base < end)
    {
        if (*((unsigned char*)base) != 0)
        {
            printf("ASM HEX: 0x%x \n", *((unsigned char*)base));
            total += *((unsigned char*)base);
        }
        base++;
        i++;
    }

    printf("i=%d\nTotal: %d\n", i, total);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is basically adding every instruction and prints the total (also prints all the instructions but I removed it for clarity). There is only one `.text`/code section.

```
PS C:\Users\buildman\Source\Repos\Test\Debug> For ($i=1; $i -lt 10; $i++)  {.\Test.exe | findstr "Total"}
```

> Total: 124027
>   Total: 141202
>   Total: 123952
>   Total: 141502
>   Total: 125677
>   Total: 125677
>   Total: 122602
>   Total: 140302
>   Total: 140302

The question is **Why is the total different each time?**
From one compilation to another I understand, but I ran the same code 10 times in a row and some instructions are different... What are those added instructions, and why?

Running it in Windows 7 but compiled for v110_XP. Inside a VM.

Thank you.

Edit 1: Maybe it's because of ASLR, but isn't it supposed to be random? If the addresses were random, the sum will always be different.

Comment: From a quick skim of your question, if you're doing some kind of checksum on the `.text` section at runtime, your result is probably affected by ASLR of absolute addresses which require runtime fixups (relocations).  Anywhere in your data or machine code that has an absolute address has to get modified by ASLR.  (Not posting as an answer because I barely looked at your code and IDK exactly how you compiled.  If your code is purely position-independent you wouldn't see any change from ASLR)

Comment: Also note that you can't just search for `0xcc` and assume that's an `int3`.

Comment: It's position independent. Yes ASLR is activated but the position is taken from the header.
@Jester yes yes I know xD it's just a simplification. My dumb sum is some kind of checksum.

Comment: @Jester that's what makes the checksum a better idea.

Comment: I think you misunderstood @PeterCordes comment about ASLR.  If it's active then the code itself will need to be fixed at load time, which will change the content of any instruction that has an address embedded in it.

Comment: @MarkRansom hooooooo. Maybe. Not at work anymore so I can't check but that's probably why... So to fix the code I need to only take the instructions, like mov, lea, etc but not the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PeterCordes is right (look in the comments). It's because of ASLR, I just tested the code with ASLR Off and the sum is always the same.